# Domestic-domestic at Manchester, UK: any security to clear?

Tags: uk, airport-security, short-connections, man

I have a potential domestic-to-domestic connection early next week at Manchester Airport, UK (MAN). I'd be connecting Flybe to Flybe, online (one ticket), all in Terminal 3. Scheduled layover is 35 minutes, which is exactly the minimum connect time in the circumstances.

I notice that the minimum connect time is lower for dom-dom than it is for international-to-domestic—which suggests there is an airside connections route, but for some reason I never quite trust Manchester airport. I've never noticed a domestic connections route before, but then I've never looked for it.

```
STANDARD.D/D...D/I...I/D...I/I.
ONLINE    .30   .40   .45   .40
OFFLINE   .30   .40   .45   .40

Exceptions
BE-BE DD   .35 TRM 3  - 3  
BE-BE ID  1.00 TRM 3  - 3
```

Does anyone know the procedure for this—do domestic arrivals reliably get access straight into the departure lounge? Is there a chance of a bus gate putting me on the wrong side of security? Do I need to look out for a subtle connections corridor before I get to baggage claim?

Comment: Based on the [experiences discussed in this Manchester connections thread on FlyerTalk](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/u-k-ireland/1685286-manchester-connection-question.html), I'd normally say to expect problems, but given how much you already contributed to that thread I guess you already know more than I do! ;-)

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, actually I couldn't find that page I mentioned in the thread yesterday, I thought maybe they removed it.  I have not done this type of connection before at MAN and it's very tight so I was hoping someone had some insight.

Comment: Can I ask how you looked up those MCTs? It'd be useful for the short connections tag wiki, which [based on this meta discussion](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3342/what-is-a-short-connection-and-what-is-the-tag-with-name-for-and-is-it-being?noredirect=1#comment10048_3342) I seem to have been nominated to help write...

Comment: @Gagravarr I have a subscription to ExpertFlyer.com. MCTs are under the "Travel Information" tab

Comment: Bah, I was hoping it was somewhere free, never mind!

Comment: @Gagravarr You should be aware that the full information covers a lot of different options and like all air travel systems has evolved to be the opposite of how a good system designer would have designed it. The carrier labels are marketing carriers not operating carriers. Some of it is also plainly wrong. Therefore I'm not actually sure how useful it would be anyway in constructing a general guide. Here is the full unfiltered information for MAN: http://pastebin.com/CquuxgVJ

Answer (score 4):

The [Manchester Airport FAQ page has a section on Domestic to Domestic flight transfer](http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/help-and-advice/frequently-asked-questions/) which states:

> #### Transferring from a domestic flight to another domestic flight
>
> On disembarking from the aircraft check the flight information screens for the gate of your onward flight. If no gate information is shown please proceed to the Terminal 3 Departure Lounge. To enter and leave the Terminal 3 Departure lounge please note that you will be required to go through a facial biometric enrolment and reconciliation process. If you don't have your boarding card you will need your confirmation of onward travel to enrol at the biometrics. If you have your boarding card for the next leg of your trip please wait in the lounge until it is time for you to board your next flight. If you do not have a boarding card for your next flight go to the customer service desk in the departure lounge where your handling agent will be able to issue you with your boarding card.

It would therefore seem that you'll have to budget some connection time for the mentioned biometric enrolment and reconciliation process, before accessing the departure lounge at Terminal 3. Whether 35 minutes might be enough transit time is something that you might want to [ask the airport directly](http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/help-and-advice/contact-details/).

Comment: Biometrics is just a photograph. In the end I did not do this trip for other reasons. But it would be interesting to know, because I have flown into MAN from LHR a few times and never seen this transfer route.

Comment: IIRC when I have flown domestic to and from manchester there was no seggregation between arrivals and departures so you would be able to just walk directly from gate to gate.