# Brussels Air: LAX to IAD to NAP Is 1.5h at IAD sufficient given change of planes, but both United?

Tags: layovers, united-airlines, iad

Brussels Air: LAX to Washington Dulles (IAD) to NAP Is 1.5 h at Washington Dulles IAD sufficient given change of planes, but both United?

Comment: What does this have to do with Brussels Air?

Comment: United don't fly to Naples from IAD. Are you flying via Brussels? Is the flight IAD-BRU on United, or a United codeshare on Brussels Airlines?

Comment: It says Brussels Air but operated by United.

Comment: So Brussels Air to BRU, and then on to NAP?  It's certainly not IAD-NAP as UA don't fly that route...

Comment: @Doc Looks like UA950, which is scheduled to resume service today after being cancelled for the last few weeks (for obvious reasons). Though it might be cancelled again anyway...

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are flying into and out of Washington Dulles on a United Airlines plane (regardless of the codeshare).  At Dulles, all United flights (excluding some United Express flights which this will not be) arrive and depart from terminals C and D - which are really just two ends of the one terminal.

Walking between any two gates within these terminals shouldn't take more than about 10 minutes.  United officially states that you need to be at the gate for your departing international flight 30 minutes before departure (although realistically will not offload you until at least 15 minutes before), so that gives you around an hour which is plenty of time presuming your inbound flight is on time.

As both flights are on United, any checked-in luggage will be checked all the way through, so there is no need to collect it in Dulles, and no need to re-clear security.  (Note that this is true even if you are booked on 2 separate tickets due to both flights being on UA)

Answer (score 1):

The [Minimum Connection Time (UA) wiki](http://flyerguide.com/index.php/Minimum_Connecting_Times_(UA)) lists IAD Domestic-to-International as 35 minutes. 1:30 is plenty.

Comment: This is Dulles we're talking about. I'll believe 35 minutes if there's no change of terminal involved, but for this itinerary there almost certainly will be. That said, 90 minutes is almost certainly enough, but I wouldn't linger in the shops...

Comment: MCT means United will sell you a ticket if the flights are at least 35 minutes apart, nothing more. Given United timeliness record (or the complete lack of one, I must say) I would never risk such a short one but 1:30 will be fine and I don't really have another way to prove it but to quote the MCT.

Comment: Thanks so much for quick reply! I was trying to figure out if I'd have to reclaim checked bags and hoof it over somewheres (no and no, I think!), so phew.

Comment: That's the other direction.

Comment: It's only plenty if you waiting for the next flight after a delay + missed connection isn't a big deal for you. If missing the connecting flight means missing a major business meeting / cruise / wedding / etc, then given United's current performance it probably isn't enough to be safe

Comment: That website is horribly out of date (it hasn't been updated for over 10 YEARS!) and is wrong.  MCT for UA Domestic to International at IAD is now at least 45 minutes, longer for certain flights.

Comment: @Doc it's a wiki! Please update.

Comment: It's a fundamentally broken wiki.  It presumes that there is a single MCT for each airport/flight type, which is broken.  The full MCT table for UA at IAD has dozens of entries based on flight number and which terminal the flights are in.  The rest of the wiki is so horribly out of date that it's simply not funny.

Comment: I know it's much more complicated than that but do you have a better source for the MCT table?

Comment: @chx Subscription services like ExpertFlier let you look it up. I'm not aware of any free sites that give the full details, [see this comment for more](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52740/domestic-domestic-at-manchester-uk-any-security-to-clear#comment107806_52740)

Comment: @chx Having the airline rebook you on a missed flight is fine, but the problem with that here is that all the United flights out of IAD to Europe (that I could find) depart in the 5pm-6pm hour. You're potentially looking at waiting a whole day to resume your journey.